# Google Assistant Voice Interaction Open Command

Tags: android, api, voice, interaction

Is there any reliable way to check if my activity was started from the Google Assistant (with the Start/Open command) or from the launcher icon?

The documentation about the Open command states

> (Works by default; no specific intent.)

so i'm not totaly optimistic.

Comment: Technically shouldn't be any difference between the two and you should handle those actions as they are the same thing because the user is expecting to get the same result both vocally and manually

Comment: Basically you're right. but I need a different behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: **Actually NO**

The default voice command: `Open XYZ` where `XYZ` is the name of an application, actually doesn't have any information attached to let you know that the request has been processed by the *Google Assistant*.

> As I already told you, probably this is done to prevent developers to attach behaviours that users could not expect from the open command which should simply open the app and nothing else.

**Note:** If the user specifies additional commands, for example `Open XYZ and play ABC song` this results in a custom intent which you can get with `getAction()` in your `onCreate()` method as described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#PlaySearch) but this is not your specific case.

References: https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/system/#open_actions

Comment: Doesn't sound like a big problem to me.. but I guess this is Google logic

Comment: Yes, you are right and I think it's the correct logic. The `open` command is the most basic command and should not produce any side effect which a manual tap on the icon won't produce.

Comment: Why not though?

Answer (score 1):

I found following difference when debugging app if its start by Google Assistant Voice Interaction Open Command

when it is start by Google Assistant Voice Interaction Open Command

you will get "android.intent.extra.REFERRER_NAME" contain key in getIntent().getExtras()

> getIntent().getExtras().containsKey("android.intent.extra.REFERRER_NAME")

```
if(getIntent().getExtras()!= null && getIntent().getExtras().containsKey("android.intent.extra.REFERRER_NAME")){
            Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: From Voice assistance");
        }else{
            Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: Not From Voice assistance");
        }
```

but if it start from menu, you will not get that key.

May be this can solve your problem.

Comment: I don't get this key in both cases. I can get the referrer with getReferrer() but, if the launcher is Google's launcher, they both are the same package

Comment: @Vlad please check the answer I have edited it, It is patch that can be useful, not a fully fledged solution

Comment: As I said.. not getting this key at all on Nexus 6P with android 8.1